# Postgres get schema for older version?

Tags: postgresql

How can I export the schema of a table in postgres for an older version?

I have on one system 10.0 but I need to export for a 9.2.23 system, which produces a non-compatible command in my case.

Is it possible to generate the schema that is downward compatible?

```
pg_dump mydb -t 'mytable' --schema-only
```

The output of this schema is:

```
--
-- PostgreSQL database dump
--

-- Dumped from database version 10.0
-- Dumped by pg_dump version 10.0

SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET lock_timeout = 0;
SET idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = on;
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET client_min_messages = warning;
SET row_security = off;
...
```

I am using the postgress app on my mac, so installing an old version extra for this seems like a hassle. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: You *could* try to run a postgres-9.2 pg_dump frontend , connecting toyour pg-10 DB. The don't have to be on the same physical machine. (cvorrection: that does not appear to work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no supported way to do this.

You will have to edit the dump manually until it loads into 9.2.

You really shouldn't be using 9.2 any more, as it is out of support.